# TortoiseSVN - Ignoring files and folders

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Just started testing TortoiseSVN.

Actions taken:

- Created folder [project name] Repo.
- Opened [project name] Repo in Repo-Browser.
- Went to project folder in Windows.
- Right-clicked on file to be ignored.

  - Selected TortoiseSVN from menu.
  - No ignore option present.
- Tried other files/folders. Same.

Help? Thanks.

Edit:

Options in the menu, with the Repo-Browser open and clicking on [project].csproj:

- Repo-Browers
- Settings
- About

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you select 'SVN Commit' from the menu, then select the file/folder you will be able to Ignore from there.

Otherwise, you can select 'TortoiseSVN > Properties' and manually add a 'SVN:ignore' entry there.

Note: you cannot ignore a file once it has been committed. You must unversion it and then ignore it.

Comment: There is no 'SVN Commit' option.

Comment: In Windows, if you right click on your working directory, there should be a 'Commit SVN ...' option, a 'SVN Update' and a 'TortoiseSVN' menu option.

Comment: Do you mean the working copy? Ok, that makes sense. I do that before committing?

Comment: What proprery value should I enter ? Is it something like "D:/Projets/projet1/toexclude_folder" or just "toexclude_folder" or "%SVN_Project_Directory_Home/projet1/toexclude_folder" or else ? Should I type it with {} or [] or <<>> or "" or '' or else ? Where is the doc for this functionallity?

Answer (score 8):

> Step 1) Right Click on Project Repository

> Step 2) Select TortoiseSVN

> Step 3) Next Select Settings (Setting Popup will be open)

> Step 4) In General tab you will see the Subversion Panel

> Step 5) In Subversion panel You will see "Global ignore pattern", add the folder name which you want to ignore.

> Step 6) Click on Apply button then Okay.

Comment: From the SVN documentation - FYI: This ignore pattern will affect all your projects. It is not versioned, so it will not affect other users. By contrast you can also use the versioned svn:ignore or svn:global-ignores property to exclude files or directories from version control.